# How can I split a text node into spans of 3 words each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, performance

Let's say I have this div:

```
<div> Let's say these are the words in my div </div>
```

I know I can wrap every words in the div into a span this way

```
$("div").contents().wrap('<span class="wrapper"/>');
//output:  <div><span class="wrapper"> Let's say these are the words in my div</span> </div>
```

However, I would like to achieve this instead:

```
<div>
    <span class="wrapper">Let's say these</span>
    <span class="wrapper">are the words</span>
    <span class="wrapper">in my div</span>
</div>
```

***Every particular amount of words (this case: every 3 words) are to be divided into a group and each group of words is to be wrapped separately.***

---

These are what first come to my mind:

1) I think it can be achieved by using `text()` to obtain the string and `split(' ')` it to form an array with each element contains a word,  write a while loop to manipulate the array:

```
var a = 0;
var b = array.length;
while (a<b) {
    array[a] = "<span class="wrapper>" +  array[a]";
    a +=2;
    if (a>b) {
        a = b-1;
    }
    array[a] = array[a] + "</span>";
    a++;
}
```

then just simply `.join('')` the array to form a string and `$("div").html(string)`;

---

2) Or I can simply use regular expression after obtaining with `text()`:

do a global search for expressions containing `a word + a space + a word + a space + another word`

> `/(\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)/g`

replace it with it wrapped in a span

> `<span>$1</span>`

and `html()` the output before performing a `$("div").contents().eq(2).wrap('<span class="wrapper"/>')` for the odd one out if there is any.

---

These are what I've come up with and I want to know, are there better ways other than these?

And what's the best way (fastest & require least memory) to achieve it?

Comment: I'd assume the concatenating version would be faster since it isn't running a "complicated" regEx calculation, but, as I understand it (and take it with a grain of salt as I haven't run tests myself), running multiple concatenations in JS is a pretty expensive process (I believe I read this in http://eloquentjavascript.net/). So yes, I have no answer. :)

Comment: And if what you wrote does the trick, it's likely going to be faster than a jQuery version, but you need to think about what is going to "perform" in the developers brain as well.

Comment: @greg5green Yeah sure :)

Comment: I would suggest First Answer given by @Arch is efficient and will perform better than using JQuery Functions suggested by will refer to library at last which may degrade performance slightly negligible.

Comment: @ameyarote Yeah I think it is better too. It is a good idea to always avoid using jQuery when possible.

Comment: Arch, did you note my solution below?  It uses jQuery for the DOM bits, but uses JS String and Array manipulation to chunk the text.

Comment: @TheSmose yeah it is a great solution but I think I would like to use pure Javascript for the DOM object as well.

Comment: Arch, better to use a framework like jQuery for DOM stuff, as it handles older `document.layers` (NS4) and `document.all` (IE4) implementations.  I know it's 1/1,000,000 users that it will affect, but it's really not that much more overhead, and ensures reliability.

Comment: @TheSmose yeah I think you are right too.

Comment: Arch: Updated my answer with a straight DOM version anyway, for your reference :)

Comment: @TheSmose Hahas Thanks! I have also written it myself to and it seems like I did it right too!

Comment: I upvoted your solution TheSmoose, but did you really just give Netscape Navigator and IE4 as a reason to use jQuery?

Comment: Hey Arch, I added one more example for you using RegEx... should be your optimal performer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do what you want:

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/UQk7r/

```
$("div").each(function() {
    var out = [];
    var words = $(this).text()..trim().split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i += 3) {
        out.push('<span class="wrapper">' + words.slice(i, i+3).join(' ') + '</span>');
    }
    $(this).html(out.join(' '));
});
```

Here's the DOM version (no jQuery):

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cCege/2/

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var out = [];
    var words = divs[i].innerText.trim().split(' ');
    for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j += 3) {
        out.push('<span class="wrapper">' + words.slice(j, j+3).join(' ') + '</span>');
    }
    divs[i].innerHTML = out.join(' ');
}
```

Finally, here's a DOM + RegEx version... this should be your optimal performer:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xgm5q/1/

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].innerHTML = '<span class="wrapper">' 
            + divs[i].innerText.trim().replace(/(([^\s]+\s+){2}[^\s]+)\s+/g, '$1</span> <span class="wrapper">')
            + '</span>';
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

For performance :

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var j=elems.length; j--;) {
    var txtArr = elems[j].textContent.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+)/g, '$1 $2 $3* ').split('*'),
        txtElm = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        span   = document.createElement('span');

    for (i=0; i<txtArr.length; i++) {
        if (/\S/.test(txtArr[i])) {
            var sp   = span.cloneNode(true),
                text = document.createTextNode(txtArr[i]);

            sp.appendChild(text);
            txtElm.appendChild(sp);
        }
    }

    elems[j].innerHTML = '';
    elems[j].appendChild(txtElm)
}
​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x2vfZ/)

Comment: Would DOM manipulation be faster than String/Array manipulation?  I'd bet no. ;)

Comment: @TheSmose - lets try it out and see -> [**JSPERF**](http://jsperf.com/funny-stuff)

Comment: Nice.  +1 for you.  FTI, here's with my regex one fixed: http://jsperf.com/funny-stuff/2

Comment: @TheSmose - could'nt get that last one working, and did'nt spend any time fixing it, but mine is still fastest in my browser, but that's really all because of the use of a fragment and only altering the DOM once (technically twice), and that's where the lag is in functions like this.